# Is there any method of TextField for selecting all text in it when get focused?

Tags: codenameone

A user has to delete existing characters in a textfield before entering new content.
Is there any method of textfield for selecting all text in it when getting focused?
A user can enter new content directly and don't have the delete the existing content character by character.

Comment: On the device I think that's the default behavior so I would suggest you don't do anything before verifying that. We have a `TextSelection` class but I doubt it will work for this specific case.